# swift - How to make size height view in navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I want to ignore navigation bar and make full size view in navigation controller.
But the view is shown under the navigation bar. 
Could I overlap navigation bar with black view?

[image]

I want to make like this picture
[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I didn't use code. I just used storyboard

Comment: Present your view instead of push. It will cover full screen of your window and hide navigation bar.

Comment: present it modally rather push.

Comment: Edited it. I want to make uploaded picture. If I don't use Present, Is it impossible?

Comment: Or you can hide navigationBar for particulat this controller.

Comment: I want to overlap navigation bar and view

Comment: This is perfect example of presenting modal view controller with modalPresentationStyle fullScreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the given UI you should add the top view on window.To do so, First make an xib of top view. then add given code:

```
    let frame = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame
    let wrapper = UIView(frame: frame!)
    wrapper.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.35)

    let objView = YourView() // Create your view object here.
    objView.frame = wrapper.frame
    objView.center = wrapper.center
    wrapper.addSubview(objView)

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(wrapper)
```

Set frame of `YourView` according to your requirement. `wrapper` makes your view transparent. You can make single view without `wrapper`. Use same code to add your view on window.